# How do I link my SpringBoot application to a specific keycloak client?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, oauth-2.0, keycloak

I'm trying to implement an authentication system for my spring boot application using keycloak using password grant flow , and it works fine for the most part there's one bit I dont understand.

(I'm gonna reference the sample source from javacodegeeks because I'm learning it through their guide.)

In this guide: https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/keycloak-in-a-spring-boot-application/

It says to setup the following configuration on my application.properties :

```
# application configuration
server:
  port: 9000
# keycloak configuration
keycloak:
  # name of the created realm
  realm: jcgassignment
  # name of the created client
  resource: spring-security-demo-app
  # indicates that our service has been created as a bearer-only (by default it is false)
  bearer-only: true
  # url of our Keycloak server
  auth-server-url: 'http://localhost:8100/auth'
```

and if I'm understanding this right, this config specifically links my springboot app with a client created within my keycloak realm. Telling my keycloak adapter to connect to this specific keycloak server, into this specific client, to verify a jwt token.

but for some reason, even if I disable the client (in this case spring-security-demo-app), my springboot app is still able to communicate with the keycloak server and verify a jwt, and thus is still able to return a 200OK response, how is that?

Is my spring boot app not correctly linked with my keycloak realm client? or am I understanding this wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add to Baptiste's answer: when you disable the client in Keycloak it means that the server will no longer issue new tokens to the client. So the client will be able to neither authenticate new users nor refresh access tokens. Still, JWTs already issued to the client (as Baptiste noted), are valid as long as the certificates haven't changed, and the token hasn't expired.

Comment: So what the adapter is doing is its just automatically verifying if the JWT is valid against the keycloak server, regardless if the client that asked to generate the token is dead or not, correct?

Comment: The JWT isn't validated "at Keycloak". What the adapter does, is it just gets the public key from the Keycloak server. Then it uses that key to verify the JWTs signature. The verification of the JWT is done in your Spring app, not by Keycloak. Spring knows nothing about the client being active or not.

Comment: Tojanowski I see, and the "verifying" part in the sample code I referenced (samplegeeks guide) in my original post,  is being handled within the KeycloakConfigController's configure() method?

Answer (score 2):

This is probably due to how a JWT is validated and how Keycloak handles his Keysets.

A client does not need the explicitly call the emitter server to authenticate a JWT, it's a stateless authentication method. Those tokens are generated with a private key when issued and then validated against a public certificate. In Keycloak those Keysets are scoped to the realm, and not to the client.

What appends is that the authentication server exposes certificates through a public URL ( for Keycloak [http://keycloak.domain.com/auth/realms/[REALM-ID]/protocol/openid-connect/certs](http://keycloak.domain.com/auth/realms/%5BREALM-ID%5D/protocol/openid-connect/certs) ), which the client uses to authenticate the token **without sending them to the authentication server**.

In short: A JWTs is valid as long as it is not expired and a certificate allows his validation.

To get back at your case, the user is authenticated on the client and the JWT is generated with the realm Keysets. If you disable the client on Keycloak after, the used keyset remains active, and so does the token.

One solution would be to disable the keyset and force refresh the cache that the client's server probably keeps.

This is inherent in how JWTs works and not specific to Keycloak.

Comment: Thanks to you I can slightly wrap my head around the problem a bit better, one more question say there are two clients in the same realm, they both ask the keycloak server to generate a token using their respective client_id and client secret (if its a client credentials flow), does keycloak have the ability to tell which token is from which client?

Comment: Yes, Keycloak has a notion of Session that you can check on the admin panel. I'm not sure of how exactly the link is done but it's more a refresh token thing than the JWT. However, the JWT's payload contains the claims `azp` (Authorized party) with the original client id, so whoever as the token can. As a side note, don't read the payload before validating the JWT as it can come from an untrusted party.

Comment: Oh neat, thanks. Also another thing, is introspection needed if I' implementing keycloak adapter on my application? From my understanding, my adapter is doing the token verification automatically.

Comment: Depends on what you mean exactly, but OpenIDC rely a lot on JSON and JSON deserialization (Jackson) in Java use introspection.

Comment: I see, I just don't see the need in sending a request to the introspect endpoint + using that information to verify a webtoken when I can just verify a webtoken by getting the public key from realm-info endpoint and comparing the signature

Comment: I'm sorry if this I'm asking too many questions, this will be the last.
How do I set up a client in a way that prevents the client from accessing the Introspect end point? Is that even possible? I've read the documentations and it's either I'm too stupid to understand it, or I completely missed it

Comment: Not that I know of directly in Keycloak. But depending on your real architecture in production, if there is a reverse proxy in front of Keycloak, you could just disable the route.